# Having this psql error: 'extra command-line argument ignored'

Tags: postgresql, shell, command-line, sh, psql

I'm currently trying to run a `.sh` file which will backup my database.

The initial psql command is as follows:

`psql -h "$HOSTNAME" -U "$USERNAME" -W "$PASSWORD" -At -c "$SCHEMA_ONLY_QUERY" postgres`

I'm getting the error:

`psql: warning: extra command-line argument "postgres" ignored`

I'm not sure if I followed the psql documentation properly, because if I remove the `-W "$PASSWORD"` part then it suddenly works but I have to enter the password every time.

I want to include the password so that it doesn't ask me for password repeatedly.

Comment: You can't specify a password with the `-W` switch.